# The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an Application which connects to a WebService to get data from database, the issue is when I tried to add web reference I get this error I get this error "The request failed with HTTP status 403 : Forbidden." and there isn't any option to add the api key or any other parameters just the URL and once I fill it the error appear and I don't know what should I do? Any help would be appreciated.

[here is a screenshot of the error when I try to add the web reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54qlI.png)

Comment: Have you tried the url in a browser?

Comment: Yes I did it and I get the same error: {"message":"Forbidden"} , only with Apps like Postman I can make my test with a successful connection   to the WebService because there I can add the api-key in the headers configuration of Postman, but with visual studio I only have the url field when I click on "add reference". I sincerely appreciate your help

Comment: FYI : I'm using HTTPS URL

Comment: I need some code